# Quick sort, in-place or not?

Tags: quicksort, in-place

[This answer about in-place in quick sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9096823/9437175) tells that quick sort is not in-place.

But, mit-ocw lecture of quick sort tells that quick sort is in-place. [MIT Lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNB2lADK3_s)

What is right answer? In-place or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Quicksort in-place or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028117/is-quicksort-in-place-or-not)

Comment: @Annabelle I saw that answer. It is not duplicate

Comment: Also duplicate of [Is imperative Quicksort in situ (in-place) or no?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9096787/62576)

Comment: @haram Yes, it is.